# ScheduledExecutorService to execute task at given time rate for given period

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

How do I make ScheduledExecutorService execute a task at a given time rate for a given period of time?

Then below code will make it execute at 1s rate ... but how do I limit the total period for all these repetitions

```
service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() { ... }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide an another Runnable to cancel this task.
Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    CountDownClock clock1 = new CountDownClock("A");

    Future<?> f1 = scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(clock1, 3, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Runnable cancelTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            f1.cancel(true);
        }
    };

    scheduler.schedule(cancelTask, 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: My ScheduledExecutorService is a bean ... and it may have more tasks running. Canceling this very task will cancel all the others too or no?

Comment: It's just an example of code. In this example you will only cancel "f1" task. But you can build more complicated logic, if you want. You can implement Runnable in your own class and provide it with Task that you want to cancel.